# Add New Item To NSDictionary Doesn't Work

Tags: xamarin.ios, nsdictionary

I use Xamarin.ios with the below code:

```
var dict = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.DictionaryForKey("TheDictKey");
if (dict == null)
{
    dict = new NSDictionary();
    NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetValueForKey(dict,(NSString)"TheDictKey");
}
dateTime = dateTime.ToUniversalTime();
dict[(NSString)"ValueKey"] = new NSString("Value"); //<------ throw exception here
```

The last sentence alway throw exception "NotSupported".

How can I update the dictionary?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That is because `NSDictionary` is immutable. That means that after it is created, you cannot change it. Use `NSMutableDictionary` for this purpose instead, which is a subclass of `NSDictionary`.

From Apple's `NSDictionary` reference:

```
NSDictionary creates static dictionaries, and NSMutableDictionary creates dynamic dictionaries.
```

Here: [click](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)